# How to put a powershell command into Sysprep's deployment script

Tags: powershell, sysprep

I need to put this command that works in PowerShell into the deployment file of SysPrep (FirstLogonCommands => SyncronousCommand area).

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers |Where-Object {$_.InstallLocation -like "*SystemApps*"} | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

How would you call powershell to execute that command so that it can be executed correctly on the first startup (Windows Server 2022)?

Comment: Are you asking how to form the command to run this using `powershell.exe` or are you asking how to configure `FirstLogonCommands`?

Comment: I'm asking how to recall it using "powershell -command ..."